# How to inject interrupts in KVM virtual machine

Tags: python, kvm

I am toying around with KVM on Intel x86-64, writing a Python wrapper for the API.

I got it to the point where I can run some 16-bit real-mode code and do `in/out` instructions as well as MMIO reads and writes.

For my next step, I was trying to configure an interrupt controller and inject an IRQ into the guest, but none of my attempts at doing this seem to work.

I tried using `KVM_CREATE_IRQCHIP` and configuring the IRQ routes to go to the master/slave PIC as well as the APIC, but even if I do that, executing `KVM_IRQ_LINE` does not seem to redirect the execution flow to an interrupt handler, instead the guest code continues to execute linearly.

Same behavior if I don't configure the in-kernel APIC and use `KVM_INTERRUPT`, and even with `KVM_NMI` the guest doesn't seem to be affected in any way.

I checked that the interrupt enable flag is turned on in the guest's `EFLAGS` register.

Is there a sanctioned way to configure a guest VM such that I can inject an interrupt into it via KVM? And if so, can anyone shed some light on how to do this? I am happy to take C/C++ code and adapt it to my Python environment, but I would appreciate step-by-step guidance!

Thanks.